# For curves $C$ of genus $1$, the period (or index?) of $C$ is greater than $1$ iff $C(k)$ is empty

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves

As the title suggests, does anyone have a reference for the proof of this fact? Actually, I can't remember where I've seen it before, or if I even remembered the statement correctly. Here are some conditions and definitions:

I assume the curve $C$ to be smooth geometrically connected over a number field $k$, I'm *not sure* if we need to assume properness here. Number field is just what I'm interested in, although the definitions below suit all fields, at least those of characteristic zero, I believe.

The *period* of a curve is the smallest positive degree of Galois-invariant divisor classes, i.e., divisor classes of $\bar{C} = C \times_k \bar{k}$ which are invariant under the action of $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)$.

The *index* is the greatest common divisor of $[K:k]$, where $K$ varies over finite algebraic field extensions for which $C(K) \neq \emptyset$. In particular, if $C(k) \neq \emptyset$ then $C$ has index $1$.

For clarity, I shall repeat my question here: If $C$ has genus $1$, is any of the following true?

1. $C(k) = \emptyset \iff C$ has period greater than $1$;
2. $C(k) = \emptyset \iff C$ has index greater than $1$.

If so, where do I find a reference for the proof(s)?

Comment: I think that both are true. For (1), if $C(k)$ is empty, then $Pic_{C/k}^1(k)$ is empty (since $Pic_{C/k}^1=C$). Hene the period of $C$ is greater than 1. For (2), the period divides the index (since any zero cycle of degree n on $C$ would produce a point in $Pic_{C/k}^n(k)$). This should be in Lichtenbaum's paper on the period-index problem for elliptic curves.

Comment: @Eoin  The greatest common divisor divides the least degree, not the other way around.  Presumably there could be $K$-points for finite field extensions $K/k$ of degrees $2$ and $3$, for instance, so that the GCD equals 1, yet there may be no rational point.  I believe the actual result here is due to Poonen-Voloch . . .

Comment: @Eoin By *zero cycle*, do you mean the Galois-invariant divisor class?

Comment: I checked, and the Poonen-Voloch result is for global function fields rather than for global number fields.

Comment: @JasonStarr: an invariant divisor class here corresponds to a point on the Picard scheme (which need not be represented by a divisor (over the base field)) so I think Eoin is right.

Comment: I missed that the divisors are not assumed to be effective.  Of course when you allow ineffective divisors the answer is different.